# nginx url rewrite with proxy pass example?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, proxy

I need to know how do i do a proxy pass in nginx for certain url pattern only

i have written following but i am not sure whether its working as i wanted. What i wanted is

```
1. if the url matches '/member-chat' it needs to be redirected the proxy pass 
2. anything else needs to be re-written as below
```

is what have written is correct ?

```
location ^/member-chat {
    proxy_pass http://lxx.com:5280/http-bind;
}
location !/member-chat {
    rewrite ^/files/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /_files/$1/$2;
    rewrite ^/plugins/([^.]+) http://www.lxx.com:9090/plugins/$1;
}
```

if i do this as below

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/files/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /_files/$1/$2;
    rewrite ^/plugins/([^.]+) http://www.lxx.com:9090/plugins/$1;
}
```

i get a error

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /var/www/vhosts/system/lxx.com
/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:4
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues:

Your location #1 `location ^/member-chat` is wrong
because ^ to match the beginning of the path only works with regular expression matching (`location ~` or `location ~*` for case-sensitive/-insensitive expression matching).

*Either* do `location /member-chat` which will **also** match locations like `/member-chatABCDE` or `/member-chat/xyz`
*or* use `location = /member-chat` to **only** match `/member-chat`.

You *can* also use regular expressions like `location ~ ^/member-chat` (prefix-match) or `location ~* ^/member-chat$` (exact match), but avoiding regular expressions in favor of prefix or even better exact matches is recommended
(regular expressions have much worse performance and are compared at the very last in the matching process).

Location #2 is just plain wrong because there is nothing like a `not` operator for location matching.
nginx will process locations in a certain order, e.g. it will start with exact matches (`=`), then check for prefix-matches (no modifier) and afterwards check for regular expressions (`~` or `~*`).
However, if a regular expression match is found, it will be favored over the prefix-match.

---

**Conclusion**

```
location = /member-chat {
  # exact match
  # proxy stuff for chat goes here
}

location /files {
  # match files 
}

location /plugin {
  # match plugin 
}
```

---

I **really** recommend you to read the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to prevent you from asking one question after another.
E.g. *location matching* is a complex topic but so far well covered by the docs already.

Comment: thank-you so much..but this didnt work because of the "error nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or i..."

Comment: @mahen3d Your edit description is wrong. For me, `location = /xy {} location /` is perfectly valid. It might have to do with `proxy_pass` as the error says, but you didn't give enough details on this.

Comment: yes, in the nginx doc, proxy_pass directive has special requirements i.e must have trailing slashes..etc may that the case... anyway thanks very much for the support, i think ngix doc is pretty good and clear, unlike the apache garbabe